# jQuery UI autocomplete's select event not triggered with Tag-it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

[Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/102/)

Can anyone tell me how to make the suggestions append to the input box on click?
I have used `Select` event like this:

```
$("#tags").tagit({
  autocomplete: {
  source: availableTags, 
  select: function (event, ui) {
  $(this).val(ui.item.value);
  },
  create: function () {       
    $(this).data("ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
     var inner_html = ''+item.value+'';
     return $("<li></li>")
      .data("item.autocomplete", item)
      .append(inner_html)  
      .appendTo(ul);
    };
  }        
 }
})
```

But the suggestions are unclickable in the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>You forgot a dot before your ui-autocomplete class.
Line 8 should read :</del>

```
$(this).data(".ui-autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
```

**EDIT**: I made some changes to the code, apparently you need to use:

`.data("ui-autocomplete-item", item)`

And what was preventing the click was the .append() line. I changed it to 
 `.append("<a>" + item.label + "</a>" )` .

Heres a working fiddle with no console errors. http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/114/

Btw, the dot had nothing to do with it, im sorry.

Comment: Thank you. It works, but the dot would cause this error to show up in the console: `Cannot set property '_renderItem' of undefined`. [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/EZ56N/109/)